# Need to call the meteor js function from php

Tags: meteor

Is it possible to call the meteor functions from php. i need to call like this for integrate the new package on my site. the package in meteor js.

If it is possible please give the example for this

Comment: Are you wanting to call a PHP script from the client as in an AJAX call?

Comment: no  i want call meteor function from php

Comment: Do you have a meteor server running? You cannot simply evaluate JS that is written for a completely different set of API (and in a different language) from the context of your PHP server, if that is what you intended to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a simple one! In php you can do something with a http call such as `file_get_contents("http://yoursite.com/api/yourfunction?variableOne=1");`
Or even curl if you want

And in Meteor (assuming you understand Iron Router and server side routes) do something like

```
Router.route( "/api/yourfunction", function() {  var variableOne = this.request.header.variableOne;
        this.response.statusCode = 200; //Post your status code
        this.response.end();}, { where: "server" });
```

If you are making a CORS request, remember to allow access to cross servers (don't use the wildcard *)

```
this.response.setHeader( 'access-control-allow-origin', '*' );
```

Edit: Did this answer help? If so please rate it